# Custom mysql MembershipProvider

Tags: mysql, asp.net-membership

I've set up a custom membership provider and everything seemed to go well.  It built out my tables automatically and I thought I was well on my way.  However, after I stubbed out the MembershipProvider I expected there to be more documentation online.  I've got tables and stubs but no logic.  I would have expected the autoschema setting to have created the stored procedures for me as well, seeing how that is where most of the logic would be.

What have I missed?

Tables built automatically by the MembershipProvider were:
my_asp_applications
my_asp_membership
my_asp_profiles
my_asp_roles
my_asp_schemaversion
my_asp_sessioncleanup
my_asp_sessions
my_asp_users
my_asp_usersinroles

Comment: Since you implemented custom membership provider (instead of using default one), you took care off the logic by yourself. Or I'm not really understanding your question.

Comment: Well that would make sense but there were a series of tables added automatically because (i think) I specified autogenerateschema="true" in the web config.  And while that is fine I think is irresponsible to  only add half the data structures.